# Upgrade from Sitecore 10.0.1 (update 1) to Sitecore 10.0.3 (update 3)

Tags: upgrade

There are some PCI compliance issues reported with Sitecore 10.0.1 (CD) image. I want to upgrade from Sitecore 10.0.1 to Sitecore 10.0.3 so is upgrading CD(10.0.3) , CM and ID (to use sitecore-id6) images sufficient and use 10.0.1 images for rest of the services ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to upgrading your Sitecore environment to address PCI compliance issues, it is generally recommended to upgrade all components to the latest version to ensure a consistent and secure setup. While it may be tempting to upgrade only the CD **(Content Delivery)** server, CM **(Content Management)** server, and ID **(Identity)** server, and leave the other services on the **10.0.1** version, it is not the ideal approach.

Sitecore releases new versions to address security vulnerabilities, bug fixes, and introduce enhancements. By upgrading all the components to Sitecore 10.0.3, you ensure that your entire environment is up-to-date and benefits from the latest security patches and improvements.

Leaving some services on an older version could introduce compatibility issues and potential security vulnerabilities, which may impact the overall security and stability of your Sitecore deployment.

**Therefore, it is recommended to upgrade all the relevant components, including CD, CM, ID, and any other services, to Sitecore 10.0.3 to ensure a consistent and secure environment.**

Comment: Upgrading your entire system is the only option. Anything else would not be supported. Its not a recommendation, its a requirement.